# From the Salafi perspective, is the prohibition of depictions of humans and animals retrospective?

Tags: art, salafi

Daesh destroyed some artwork last year on the grounds that it depicted humans or animals, which isn't permitted by Islam.

From the Salafi perspective, is the prohibition of depictions of humans and animals retrospective? That is, does it apply to artwork from before the time of Mohammed?

Comment: good question, but you need to give some more details and what you have already researched on this topic.

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin done.

Answer (score 2):

*[Note: The answer is from the mainstream Salafi perspective (cause the OP asked for it)]*

> OP asked: From the Salafi perspective, is the prohibition of depictions of humans and animals retrospective?

Yes. According to this IslamQA [fatawa](https://islamqa.info/en/20894) (IslamQA is one of the most respected source of mainstream salafi doctrine), it is obligatory to destroy idols. It states:

> The evidence of sharee’ah indicates that it is obligatory to destroy
>   idols, for example:
>
> 1 – Muslim (969) narrated that Abu’l-Hayaaj al-Asadi said: ‘Ali ibn
>   Abi Taalib said to me: “Shall I not send you with the same
>   instructions as the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him) sent me? ‘Do not leave any image without defacing it or
>   any built-up grave without leveling it.’”
>
> 2 – Muslim (832) narrated from ‘Urwah ibn ‘Abasah that he said to the
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): “With what were
>   you sent?” He said, “I was sent to uphold the ties of kinship, to
>   break the idols, and so that Allaah would be worshipped alone with no
>   partner or associate.”

Answer (score 1):

It is. Once something is made Haram -for example wine, it is haram regardless of when it was made. When wine was made Haram, people started throwing the wine away until the streets were all filled with wine.

Unless someone corrects me, this is not just a Salafi thing, but rather Muslims, Jews and Christians. Once something is forbidden by a religion it is retrospective.

Finally, it would make it easier to understand your question to say Prophet (if you believe it to be so) Mohamed instead of Aisha's Husband.